# Why do reputation points of a user have a wrong value shown in user search?

Tags: bug, search

Today I was searching my own profile, and I found this bug *(might be not)*.

When I search for a user, it shows the wrong reputation points in the search result. Can you please justify why this is so?

Here what I can see in search:

[image: User in search]

Here are the actual reputation points:

[image: Actual reputation]

Comment: If you look to the right you can confirm the period that is being shown on the search users. For me, the default period is pretty... unuseful

Comment: [What do the numbers on the Users page mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167435/what-do-the-numbers-on-the-users-page-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the reputation you've achieved this week.

[image]

Click on "all" and you'll get the full count.